# Is it bad practice to have a set method without its own get method?

Tags: c++, class, accessor

Let's say I have a class (the name circle was random and has no significance):

```
Class circle{
    double colorFrequency_;
public:
    void setColor(double colorFrequency){ colorFrequency_=colorFrequency; }
    void setColor(string colorName){ colorFrequency_=colorNameToFrequency(string colorName); } 
    double getColorFrequency()
    string getColorName(){ /* converts color frequency into a string containing the name of a color it's close to, like "red" */ }

}
```

On one hand, it seems inconsistent to have a method called setColor but not one called getColor, but on the other hand, if I were to instead have functions called setColorFrequency and setColorName, then those names would not be completely descriptive since setColorName would not only affect the output of getColorName, but also the output of setColorFrequency.

Is it too strange to have a function called setColor, but not one called getColor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on whether you want the member value to be obtained by the users of your class.

So unusual or not, you should stick to what your design demands.

Comment: While I agree to respect your design, in this case nothing (shown) forces you to use overloading on setColor; setColorFrequency and setColorName would be sensible too.

Comment: @Jürgen Strobel setColorFrequency and setColorName sound like they would update two *different* things -- whereas they do not. perhaps setColorFromName or setColorFromFrequency if overloading is to be avoided...

Comment: @pst How about 'SetColor(double colorFreq)' and 'SetColorFromName(string colorName)'. It seems more clear to me to describe what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

One well-known design where you might need `SetModel()` function but `GetModel()` doesn't make sense is : Model-View-Presenter (MVP) Pattern or its variants (such as MVC, MVVM etc)

For last one year I'm mostly working on UI, where I've implemented MVP following Prism architecture (WPF and Silverlight). Our design goes something like this:

```
//C# code, but this design can written in C++ as well
public class QueryPresenter : IQueryPresenter, /*other interfaces */
{

   public QueryPresenter(IQueryView view, /*other parameter*/)
   {
     //...
     view.SetModel(this);
   }
}
```

That is, its the presenter which calls the `SetModel` function of the view to set itself as model for the view, but there is no `GetModel` function in view class because it doesn't make sense at all.

So yes, it entirely depends on the design where you might need set function, but get function may not make sense. Usually such set functions are used to "configure" the object which will be used in some other way, like in MVP pattern. Set functions can also be used in designs where few classes work in a cooperative way. Such classes may be `friend`  of each other so that they can access each other `private` members (if required).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how strange it is, but one might consider renaming the mutators to `changeColor` (or something similarly different) to make it clearer that there's no getter/setter "pairing".

Personally, I would prefer to leave the conversion completely indepent of `Circle` and let the caller handle it:

```
double colorNameToFrequency(const string& name) { ... }
string colorFrequencyToName(double frequency) { ... }

class Circle
{
    double colorFrequency_;
public:
    void setColor(double colorFrequency);
    double getColor() const;
};

// Client code 
Circle c;
c.setColor(colorNameToFrequency("mint-green"));
string name = colorFrequencyToName(c.getColor());
```

This makes the `Circle` class independent of whatever you choose as a human-readable format for colors.